# List to list of tuples in haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

In Haskell, say I have a list of `Int`s, which I know is of a length that is a multiple of 4.

How might I write a function that changes the list into a list of `(Int, Int, Int, Int)` tuples instead?

Eg:

`int2tuplelist :: [Int] -> [(Int, Int, Int, Int)]`

Comment: What, if anything, have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int2tuplelist (x1:x2:x3:x4:xs) = (x1,x2,x3,x4): int2tuplelist xs
int2tuplelist []               = []
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks so much!